# Force a single background image to *NOT* cache

Tags: asp.net, http, iis-7, http-headers, iis-7.5

I have a div tag on my site that uses a background image.  When we make a tiny text change in that image and ftp it back to the server, it continues to serve it as 304 not modified and uses the cached version.  Only until we force a browser refresh does it fetch the new image.

I've read where you can set Cache-Control to no-cache in the HTTP Response Headers (I'm using IIS 7.5), but that still does nothing, still uses the cached image and sends back a 304.   My workaround was to rename the image and also change the div's css and that does work, but I'm looking for a better way.   Ideally, we want this single image to be dynamic so we can change it often, but we don't want our customers to have to know to refresh their browsers.

Is there a solution?

Comment: AFAIK, there's no reliable way to do this on a server. I've been trying to solve a similar task, but the best solution is still a workaround: we have a js function which updates image by adding a random parameter to it's src every now and then.

Comment: shiftoff's comment may be right on the money: adding a parameter to the img src URL may force the server to re-send the image since servers usually served cached content based on parameters in the Query string. If the query string changes, IIS should send the new version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing url is most common workaround.
 In my case, when I've experienced such issue, I've moved image in separate controller(or it may be page, or even hadler), and was adding little url param, which was generated by `datetime` class, e.g.:

```
http:\\mysite.com\myimage\dynamic.jpg?bla=20121119184001
```

Comment: This solution is viable, used it many time before to force new images or new javascript updates. However, the image does not specifically need to be dynamically server. You can add the random parameter to any request. The webserver will ignore it for static content and serve the file.

Comment: Just to take this further, if you want to do this reliably, you should append the `lastmodified` time of the file to the url to retrieve it - eg `background.jpg?date=20121119144300` This way, every time you update the file, the url for retrieving it will change, forcing a new cache entry - but if you haven't modified it, you still get the benefits of caching

Comment: Yes, indeed. After wasting too much time in server configs, aspx page markup cache parameters, response headers and etc, I've decided that this workaround is simplest solution.

Comment: I never thought of adding a parm.  Going to try this!